# Xpath: Working in Devtools but returns empty object with document.evaluate()

Tags: node.js, xpath, document.evaluate

The following command works as expected in Devtools console (for example, here - https://news.ycombinator.com/)

`$x('//a[@class="storylink"]')` (Edge browser)

But the following code:

```
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto("https://news.ycombinator.com/");
            let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
                var item = document.evaluate(
                    '//a[@class="storylink"]',
                    document,
                    null,
                    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
                    null
                ).singleNodeValue;
                return item
            })
            browser.close();
```

returns an empty object: `{}`. The same is happening in every other website.
Why is that happening?

Comment: //*[@id='pagespace'] doesn't contain any value

Comment: @Fazlul I edited to another query, still ```{}```

Comment: Is that using Puppeteer? It exposes an XPath evaluation method `$x` on the `page` you have: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.4.0&show=api-pagexexpression. `let urls = await page.$x('//a[@class="storylink"]')`.

Comment: I have put the suggestion of the comment into answer so that you can accept it to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are automatic Chrome with Puppeteer from Node.js then the `page` object you have already exposes a method `$x` for XPath evaluation, see https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.4.0&show=api-pagexexpression. That means that doing

```
let urls = await page.$x('//a[@class="storylink"]')
```

should suffice.